# How to pass a value to database without f.text_field Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi guys i have a value which i wan't to add to the database dynamically. The value is made with jQuery and it outputs to the **`id 'invoice_total'`**.
So based on the users input that value changes. 
I want to save that value to the database while using something like `<p id="invoice_total"></p>` and not `<%= f.text_field :total, id: 'invoice_total' %>`

How can i achieve this with RoR?

Comment: If you dont want to submit a form or use a form field, then you should send it as a `GET params` i.e through `url`. you can do a `GET` request through Ajax to your `controller`.

Comment: Ajax call to this kind of url: `http://example.com/invocie?invoice-total="value of invoice total"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hidden field and when set the value to `p` set this input value:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :total, id: 'invoice_total_input' %>
```

and then you can do:

```
$('#invoice_total_input').val(...)
```

Comment: I tried; <%= f.hidden_field :total, class: 'invoice_total' %>
                      <p class="invoice_total"></p>... it works as in it doesn't give any errors but somehow it saves the values to the database as 0.00

Comment: @luissimo thats because you need to update your `text-field` value when user makes any changes to their input through js/jQuery

Comment: Yeah i was doing that but i was giving the value a symbol aswell which is not allowed. Well it works now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to submit a form or use a form field, then you should send it as a `GET params` i.e through `url`. you can do a `GET` request through Ajax to your `controller`

You can do it when the value of `#invoice_total` changes.

In your `/assets/javascripts/invoices.js` file

```
$("#invoice_total").on('change', function(){
var invoice_total = $('#invoice_total').val();
    $.get( "url/to/controller's-action", function() {
          alert( "success" );
    });
});
```

Then in your `Controller`

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    total_invoice = params[:invoice_total]
    # .....save the value to DB
  end
end
```